# PySide text in QLineEdit not editable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I making a console like program for my application. I have a QLineEdit that takes up the whole height of the screen, where the user will be able to input the commands.  I want to add "prompts" for instance 'hostname:current_dir># ' after the # the user will put the command. I want that prompt to NOT be editable (he can just backspace it away) but still have the user be able to type commands.  Any ideas? Or may someone suggest a better way of doing this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a slot to the [`cursorPositionChanged ()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlineedit.html#cursorPositionChanged) signal, check its position, and disable editing with [`setEnabled(False)`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#setEnabled). You might also want to take a look into [`QTextEdit`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextedit.html), [`QTextBrowser`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextbrowser.html) or [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qplaintextedit.html), where you could use the [`setReadOnly`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextedit.html#setReadOnly) method.